# How to subscribe to TypedEventHandler<T, TArgs> event using IObservable

Tags: system.reactive

I was trying the following,

```
var _connectedAnimation = ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().GetAnimation("forwardAnimation");

Observable.FromEvent<TypedEventHandler<ConnectedAnimation, object>, object>(
          handler => _connectedAnimation.Completed += handler,
          handler => _connectedAnimation.Completed -= handler)
```

However, when the event is raised I get the runtime exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
  at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
  at System.Reactive.ReflectionUtils.CreateDelegate[TDelegate](Object o, MethodInfo method) in D:\a\1\s\Rx.NET\Source\src\System.Reactive\Internal\ReflectionUtils.cs:line 24
  at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.FromEvent`2.GetHand
```

The completed event is defined as

```
public sealed class ConnectedAnimation : IConnectedAnimation, IConnectedAnimation2, IConnectedAnimation3
{
    /// <summary>Occurs when the animation is finished.</summary>
    public extern event TypedEventHandler<ConnectedAnimation, object> IConnectedAnimation.Completed;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is not a standard event and also because there are multiple event arguments, we need to create a `Tuple`. Refer to [4.2.3. Events with multiple parameters](https://livebook.manning.com/book/rx-dot-net-in-action/chapter-4/point-4714-125-125-0) in `Rx.Net in Action`.

```
Observable.FromEvent<TypedEventHandler<ConnectedAnimation, object>, Tuple<ConnectedAnimation, object>>(
    rxHandler => (animation, o)=> rxHandler(Tuple.Create(animation,o)),
    handler => _connectedAnimation.Completed += handler,
    handler => _connectedAnimation.Completed -= handler)
```